# How to drop all tables from a database in sql server 2005 in a statement except one table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using sql-server 2005. Initially, for learning purpose I created many tables now I want to drop all those tables except one which is currently I am working on. 
Is there any code or query with which I can drop all tables from my that database except that one useful table.
One way I think is to copy that table into new database using `SELECT INTO...` clause and drop that database but don't know is this a good way to solve this problem.

Comment: If the tables aren't very big I'd probably just select them all in the "Object Explorer Details" window in SSMS then hit delete.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith this is a good way but is there any way with which I can do same thing using statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the tables aren't very big I'd probably just select them all in the "Object Explorer Details" window in SSMS then hit delete.

For a programmatic solution you could use

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachtable 
       N'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') <> OBJECT_ID(''dbo.YourTableToKeep'')
             DROP TABLE ?
       '
```

Both methods might need repeated runs in order to delete all tables involved in FK relationships (a table cannot be deleted if another table has an FK referencing it).

Comment: To elaborate a little on the UI solution: F7 is the Object Explorer Details keyboard shortcut. You can't multi-select objects in the object explorer tree view, but you can select the Tables node in the tree view and hit F7 to show the Object Explorer Details.

Answer (score 6):

You can use sql to create all drops staments that you needs. For example the next sql query

```
USE [MyDatabase];
GO
SELECT  
    replace(
        replace('DROP TABLE [{Schema}].[{TableName}];'
        ,'{Schema}',TABLE_SCHEMA)
        ,'{TableName}',TABLE_NAME) 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE 
    TABLE_NAME NOT IN ('TableNameOne','TableNameTwo')
```

and get the result executing the query.

Copy first column of the query and paste it in a new query window.

It's easy to see, that you get a list of drop staments for all tables except 'TableNameOne' and 'TableNameTwo',...

Im think that is very simple...

Answer (score 4):

```
/* Drop all Foreign Key constraints */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

WHILE @name is not null
BEGIN
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    WHILE @constraint IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']'
        EXEC (@SQL)
        PRINT 'Dropped FK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    END
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
END
GO

/* Drop all Primary Key constraints */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    WHILE @constraint is not null
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint)+']'
        EXEC (@SQL)
        PRINT 'Dropped PK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    END
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME)
END
GO

/* Drop all tables */
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name])

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE [dbo].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']'
    EXEC (@SQL)
    PRINT 'Dropped Table: ' + @name
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] = 'U' AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name])
END
GO
```